# How to validate entities in Caliburn.Micro

Tags: c#, validation, mvvm, data-annotations, caliburn.micro

I iam trying to build validation in my mvvm project but found some problem...

First i try to use CodeContract, so i have a simple contract on my entity in domain layer:

```
public class Class1 
{
    public virtual int ID {get;set;}
    private string _desc;
    public virtual string Desc 
    { 
        get { return _desc; }
        set {
            Contract.Requires(String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) == false);
            Contract.Requires(value.Length >2, "> 2 required ");
            _desc = value;
        } 
    }
    public Class1(int id)
    {this.Id = id;}
}
```

then in my Caliburn.micro Boostrapper in the Configure method i add

```
ConventionManager.ApplyValidation = (binding, viewModelType, property) =>
        { binding.ValidatesOnExceptions = true; };
```

in view i simply put

```
<TextBox x:Name="Class1Description" ></TextBox>
```

having ViewModel exposing a string property named Class1Description (i do not expose the original Class1 object)

Running application the problem is that an exception is thrown and focus switch from the form to visualstudio on the set method of my property, pressing F5 the focus return to form and the desc field is red.

How can i avoid the focus switch??

Searching validation on internet i find that IDataErrorInfo seems the best way, so i try DataAnnotation and add [MinLength(2)] to my property and change bootstrapper

```
ConventionManager.ApplyValidation = (binding, viewModelType, property) =>
{binding.ValidatesOnDataErrors = true; };
```

the new textbox in view is

```
<TextBox x:Name="Class1Description" Text="{Binding Path=Class1Description, 
     ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
</TextBox>
```

now i run application, write a one-char string in Desc textbox, switch the focus to other text-box and nothing nothing happens...

What am I missing?

Comment: in your class how does the viewmodel know if a property changed when you don't throw a notification about it? Secondly what property is to be validated? Deep binding I assume then wouldn't you need to use Class1Desc?

Comment: is caliburn.micro to tell viewmodel the change of a property in the view (based on textbox name). The property to be validated is the only one of my viewmodel (as i wrote): Class1Description . Don't understand you last question

Answer (score 0):

ok 2 things, 1 your are causing Caliburn to freak a little, don't name the control and then use binding with the same name of the Property.  Secondly in the class example you have Desc not Class1Description as the property.  Property names have to match the path.

For textboxes that are part of .net (not 3rd party) the UpdateSourceTrigger is in the framework (CM) is defaulted to PropertyChange.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Desc, ValidatOnErrors =True, Mode=TwoWay}" />

 public virtual string Desc 
{ 
    get { return _desc; }
    set {
        Contract.Requires(String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) == false);
        Contract.Requires(value.Length >2, "> 2 required ");
        _desc = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(()=>Desc); //Added
    } 
}
```

If the class isn't setup for IDataNotifyErrorInfo then you will not see any error.  Secondly if the template isn't set then it won't show much of anything either.

Comment: ok, i use primary x:name for binding but adding validatieOnErrors require the binding so i simply left all. so i will remove x:name. I do not expose model in my ViewModel: so the view is not bind to Desc property of MyClass but to Class1Description of MyClassViewModel

Comment: well then the Path would be Class1Description.Desc, otherwise it has no idea of what Class1Description is and or the property it is being bound..

Comment: i rewrite what i write in original post: having ViewModel exposing a string property named Class1Description (i do not expose the original Class1 object). Class1Description is a string property, then i use automapper to map ViewModel to Entity. Basically Class1Description is a string variable to store the value that next will be saved to Desc property of entity object